# Amazon ssl efficiency for multiple image requests

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-s3, keep-alive

I'm using S3 to host and serve a large number of images using ssl protocol, and want to minimize overhead and latency associated with the ssl handshake/negotiation. When a web page is loaded and the browser makes a large number of https requests to an S3 bucket, can I reasonably expect that the ssl handshake overhead will occur only once and the connection will be kept alive for the series of requests?

I do not see any keep-alive parameter in S3's response header indicating this is the case. Are there any manual settings that can / need to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

1. As long as you have SSL session timeouts configured, you should be only doing full handshaking once every SSL Session timeout value per client/server pair. Set it as low as you can while still deriving some benefit, to reduce session memory usage at the server. 10-15 minutes for example.
2. As long as you have HTTP keepalive configured, you won't be doing partial handshakes on resumed connections. Again set this timeout as low as you can while still retaining benefit, say 30 seconds.

Comment: Excellent guidance - thanks.  The ssl communication is direct between client browser and amazon S3 servers.  I would expect to find documentation on how/whether these settings can be configured for my S3 storage buckets, but have found nothing. Does anyone have experience with this issue specifically for S3?